# How to find distinct values from the database in cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp

I am implementing a message system like Facebook. In the preview I'd like to show the last message from a sender to that particular recipient. The problem I am getting right now is that my current code fetch all the messages to a recipient from the database.
My current code is

```
$messages = $this->Message->find('all',
  array(
   'conditions' => array('recipient_id' => $recipient_id),
   'order' => array('Message.id' => 'desc'),
   'fields' => array('DISTINCT Message.sender_id','Message.message')
  )
);
```

It does work if I use it something like this

```
$messages = $this->Message->find('all',
  array(
   'conditions' => array('recipient_id' => $recipient_id),
   'order' => array('Message.id' => 'desc'),
   'fields' => array('DISTINCT Message.sender_id')
 )
);
```

but In that case I do not get the associated last message with the unique sender.

I have researched a lot in Google and didn't find anything useful. Is it even possible? All help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what about adding second condition (sender_id), and instead of find ('all' find('first' with
   'order' => array(
                                'timestamp' => 'DESC'
                            ),

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the GROUP BY Clause:

```
$messages = $this->Message->find('all',
  array(
    'conditions' => array(
      'recipient_id' => $recipient_id,
    ),
    'order' => array(
      'Message.id' => 'DESC'
    ),
    'group' => array('Message.sender_id')
  )
);
```

[MySQL Docs on GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) 
[CakePHP Book on Find Options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find)

The GROUP BY will group the possible results by the `sender_id` providing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is frequently asked on SO with the MySQL (or some other database tag) which is part of the *Top N per Group* problem.

Assuming your messages table has these fields

- id
- sender_id
- recipient_id
- sent_date
- message_text

SQL that would return the last message per sender for recipient_id = 1 would be:

```
SELECT Message.*
FROM messages AS Message
JOIN (SELECT sender_id, MAX(sent_date) AS recent_date
      FROM messages
      WHERE recipient_id = 1
      GROUP BY sender_id) AS most_recent
  ON most_recent.sender_id = Message.sender_id
    AND most_recent.recent_date = Message.sent_date
WHERE Message.recipient_id = 1;
```

which does not translate easily to CakePHP's `find` method. Use the [query method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) instead.